# Convolutional NN training accuracy is not improving while loss is decreasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train deep convolutional neural network with on lfw pairs dataset (2200 pairs of faces, 1100 belong to the same person and 1100 do not). The problem is that while loss is decreasing during training, accuracy **on training data** remains the same or even getting worse when compared to the first epoch. I'm using quite low learning rates and this is what I got for 0.0001:

```
Epoch 0 training complete
Loss: 0.10961
Accuracy: 0.549
Epoch 1 training complete
Loss: 0.10671
Accuracy: 0.554
Epoch 2 training complete
Loss: 0.10416
Accuracy: 0.559
Epoch 3 training complete
Loss: 0.10152
Accuracy: 0.553
Epoch 4 training complete
Loss: 0.09854
Accuracy: 0.563
Epoch 5 training complete
Loss: 0.09693
Accuracy: 0.565
Epoch 6 training complete
Loss: 0.09473
Accuracy: 0.563
Epoch 7 training complete
Loss: 0.09250
Accuracy: 0.566
Epoch 8 training complete
Loss: 0.09137
Accuracy: 0.565
```

And this is what I got for 0.0005 learning rate:

```
Epoch 0 training complete
Loss: 0.09443
Accuracy: 0.560
Epoch 1 training complete
Loss: 0.08151
Accuracy: 0.565
Epoch 2 training complete
Loss: 0.07635
Accuracy: 0.560
Epoch 3 training complete
Loss: 0.07394
Accuracy: 0.560
Epoch 4 training complete
Loss: 0.07183
Accuracy: 0.555
Epoch 5 training complete
Loss: 0.06996
Accuracy: 0.563
Epoch 6 training complete
Loss: 0.06878
Accuracy: 0.556
Epoch 7 training complete
Loss: 0.06743
Accuracy: 0.538
Epoch 8 training complete
Loss: 0.06689
Accuracy: 0.538
Epoch 9 training complete
Loss: 0.06680
Accuracy: 0.549
Epoch 10 training complete
Loss: 0.06559
Accuracy: 0.542
```

So my model is implemented in Tensorflow. This is the network architecture:

```
def _get_output_ten(self, inputs_ph, embedding_dimension):
    with tf.variable_scope(self.var_scope, reuse=self.net_vars_created):
        if self.net_vars_created is None:
            self.net_vars_created = True

        inputs = tf.reshape(inputs_ph, [-1, self.width, self.height, 1])
        weights_init = random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.1)

        # returns 60 x 60 x 15
        net = tf.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=inputs,
            filters=15,
            kernel_size=(5, 5),
            strides=1,
            padding='valid',
            kernel_initializer=weights_init,
            activation=tf.nn.relu)
        # returns 30 x 30 x 15
        net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=net, pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)
        # returns 24 x 24 x 45
        net = tf.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=net,
            filters=45,
            kernel_size=(7, 7),
            strides=1,
            padding='valid',
            kernel_initializer=weights_init,
            activation=tf.nn.relu)
        # returns 6 x 6 x 45
        net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=net, pool_size=(4, 4), strides=4)
        # returns 1 x 1 x 250
        net = tf.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=net,
            filters=250,
            kernel_size=(6, 6),
            strides=1,
            kernel_initializer=weights_init,
            activation=tf.nn.relu)
        net = tf.reshape(net, [-1, 1 * 1 * 250])
        net = tf.layers.dense(
            inputs=net,
            units=256,
            kernel_initializer=weights_init,
            activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
        net = tf.layers.dense(
            inputs=net,
            units=embedding_dimension,
            kernel_initializer=weights_init,
            activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)

        net = tf.check_numerics(net, message='model')

    return net
```

I tried deeper ones but they give 0.500 or so training accuracy in all epochs no matter how long I train.
I'm using siamese architecture and contrastive loss function. This is how training is implemented:

```
def train(self, x1s, x2s, ys, num_epochs, mini_batch_size, learning_rate, embedding_dimension, margin,
          monitor_training_loss=False, monitor_training_accuracy=False):
    input1_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(mini_batch_size, self.width, self.height))
    input2_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(mini_batch_size, self.width, self.height))
    labels_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(mini_batch_size,))
    output1 = self._get_output_ten(input1_ph, embedding_dimension)
    output2 = self._get_output_ten(input2_ph, embedding_dimension)

    loss = self._get_loss_op(output1, output2, labels_ph, margin)
    loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss], message='loss')
    global_step = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

    num_batches = int(math.ceil(ys.shape[0] / mini_batch_size))

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for ep in range(num_epochs):
            x1s, x2s, ys = unison_shuffle([x1s, x2s, ys], ys.shape[0])

            for bt_num in range(num_batches):
                bt_slice = slice(bt_num * mini_batch_size, (bt_num + 1) * mini_batch_size)
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={
                    input1_ph: x1s[bt_slice],
                    input2_ph: x2s[bt_slice],
                    labels_ph: ys[bt_slice]
                })
            print('Epoch {} training complete'.format(ep))
```

This is how loss is calculated:

```
def _get_loss_op(output1, output2, labels, margin):
    labels = tf.to_float(labels)
    d_sqr = compute_euclidian_distance_square(output1, output2)
    loss_non_reduced = labels * d_sqr + (1 - labels) * tf.square(tf.maximum(0., margin - d_sqr))
    return 0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(loss_non_reduced, dtype=tf.float64))
```

This is how I measure accuracy:

```
def _get_accuracy_op(out1, out2, labels, margin):
    distances = tf.sqrt(compute_euclidian_distance_square(out1, out2))
    gt_than_margin = tf.cast(tf.maximum(tf.subtract(distances, margin), 0.0), dtype=tf.bool)
    predictions = tf.cast(gt_than_margin, dtype=tf.int32)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.not_equal(predictions, labels), dtype=tf.float32))
```

I use 0.5 margin and mini batch size of 50.
Gradient monitoring gave nothing, it seems ok. Also I monitored the distances in embedding result and looks like they are not updated in correct direction.

This is the repo with the full source code https://github.com/andrei-papou/facever. It is not so large so please check if I haven't given enough information here.

Thanks all!

Comment: It looks like you are not using any form of regularization (or maybe I missed it). A decreasing loss with constant accuracy of 50% (basically it is classifying randomly) is consistent with overfitting. How are you splitting your training, test and validation data? Try using regularization or dropout and see if it gets better

Comment: @gionni I measure accuracy on **training** data. Should regularization help here? Anyway, I'll try adding dropout, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Then there is a problem. If you were overfitting accuracy on training data would be getting higher.

Comment: Your accuracy stays at 0.5, is the prediction pointing to 1 class (either all same or nor same). Training a Siamese network is tricky are you following the `facenet` paper implementation?

Comment: @vijaym I checked the paper, but found contrastive loss much more straightforward to implement than triplet loss, especially what concerns data preparation. I just thought I could get some result quicker with the contrastive loss.